# An optimal bound

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S_1,\dots,S_k$ be subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$ where $k > 2$ and $n > 2$. From the inequality $$ \text{dim}(S_1 \cap S_2 \cap \dots S_k) \geq \text{dim}(S_1)+\dots+\text{dim}(S_k) - (k-1)n, $$ it follows that $ \text{dim}(S_1)+\dots+\text{dim}(S_k) > (k-1)n$ implies $\text{dim}(S_1 \cap S_2 \cap \dots S_k) > 0.$

I want to know if the bound $(k-1)n$ is the best possible for all $k$.

The best bound can be found from the following optimization problem,
$$
\begin{align}
\text{maximize} & & \text{dim}(S_1)+\dots+\text{dim}(S_k)\\
\text{subject to} & & S_1,\dots,S_k \text{ are subspaces of } \mathbb{C}^n\\
& & \text{dim}(S_1 \cap S_2 \cap \dots S_k) = 0.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(k-1)n$ is the optimal bound. Since $\text{dim}(S_1\cap S_2 \cap \dots \cap S_k) > 0$ if $\text{dim}(S_1) + \dots + \dim(S_k) > (k-1)n$ we must have $\text{dim}(S_1) + \dots + \text{dim}(S_k) \leq (k-1)n$ whenever $\text{dim}(S_1\cap S_2 \cap \dots \cap S_k) = 0$. The bound is attained when $S_1,\dots,S_{k-1} = \mathbb{C}^n$ and $S_k = \{ 0 \}.$